# I want alert "The balance is large!" directly

Tags: javascript

I want to skip the first condition if the balance is larger than 10000 and then the output should be "The balance is large!" directly.

Right now the code is giving me  "The balance is positive", then "The balance is large."

The code is given below:

```
var  balance = 15000;

if (balance >= 0) {
    alert("The balance is positive");
    if (balance > 10000) {
        alert ("The balance is large!");
    }
} else {
    alert("The balance is negative");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `if (balance > 10000)` before the first `if` and make that an `else if` instead.

```js
var balance = 15000;

if (balance > 10000) {
  alert("The balance is large!");
} else if (balance >= 0) {
  alert("The balance is positive");
} else {
  alert("The balance is negative");
}
```

Comment: I don't want to see "The balance is positive" at all if the balance greater than 10000 . I want out put "The balance is large" only.

I don't want to see two alerts Just one alert , are you got the idea.

Comment: That's exactly what happens with this code. You'll only see the first alert because the second condition is an `else if`, not another `if` by itself.

Comment: Thank you very much , that't what I want , just one output

Answer (score 2):

You can start by checking if the balance is greater than 10000 and do the other checks using else if, like so.

```
if (balance > 10000) {
  alert("The balance is large!");
} else if (balance >= 0) {
  alert("The balance is positive");
} else {
  alert("The balance is negative");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var  balance = 15000;
if (balance >= 0) {
   if (balance > 10000) {
      alert ("The balance is large!");
   }
   alert("The balance is positive");
} else {
  alert("The balance is negative");
}
```